# How to change title of facets in ggpredict() for ordered logit

Tags: r, ggplot2, predict

I have the following code:

```
ggpredict(df, terms=c("x"), by = "id") %>% plot() + 
  ylab("predicted probabilities") + xlab("") + ggtitle("") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0.05) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 2, 1),
    labels = c("No Answer", "No", "Yes")
  )
```

It produces a plot that looks like this:

[image]

I want to change the facet titles so I added:

```
ggpredict(df, terms=c("x"), by = "id") %>% plot() + 
  ylab("predicted probabilities") + xlab("") + ggtitle("") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0.05) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 2, 1),
    labels = c("No Answer", "No", "Yes")
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ x, labeller = labeller(x = c("0" = "A", "1" = "B", "2" = "C", "3" = "D", "4" = "E")))
```

Which gives men a graph that's way off:

[image]

I recognize that the x-axis is squished and I plan to fix that later, but right now, my primary concern is changing the facet titles.

Comment: You specified the wrong faceting variable, i.e. `x` is the variable mapped on `x`. The first plot facets by `id` whereas for the second plot you facet by `x`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data and the code used for your model.